# How to fix Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, next.js

I'm trying to render a list of items in a cart. The list of items are passed as a props from my parent component. I'm calling mapCartItemsToItems but it doesn't render and indicate that

"Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {childKey, header, meta, extra}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

```
const mapCartItemsToItems = items =>
    items.map(({ id, product_id, name, quantity, meta }) => {
      const price = meta.display_price.with_tax.unit.formatted || null

      return {
        childKey: id,
        header: (
          <Link href={`/product?id=${product_id}`} passHref>
            <div>{name}</div>
          </Link>
        ),
        meta: `${quantity}x ${price}`,
        extra: <button onClick={() => removeFromCart(id)}>Remove</button>
      }
    })
return <div>{mapCartItemsToItems(items)}</div>
```

Comment: `return {` you are returning an object?

Comment: Also, it should return JSX, not a javascript object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you're trying to use simple objects as children in an element. You can't do that in React.

If you want to use `childKey` and `header` and `meta` and `extra` in the list you're producing, you need to create an element structure in your `map` callback rather than a plain object. (Or use a second `map` later to do it, but...)

For instance (but of course, you'll have to adjust this structure to suit your needs):

```
const mapCartItemsToItems = items =>
    items.map(({ id, product_id, name, quantity, meta }) => {
        const price = meta.display_price.with_tax.unit.formatted || null

        return (
            <div key={id}>
                <Link href={`/product?id=${product_id}`} passHref>
                    <div>{name}</div>
                </Link>
                {quantity}x {price}
                <button onClick={() => removeFromCart(id)}>Remove</button>
            </div>
        )
    })
return <div>{mapCartItemsToItems(items)}</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! You made it very clear and saved me some frustration !